# Reverse values in pd.Series by their value type

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, series

I have this `pd.Series`:

```
s = pd.Series([1, 'a', 1.4, 'b', 4, 98, 6.7, 'hello', 98.9])
```

My goal is to switch the values by each value type in reverse order.

My desired output is:

```
>>> s = pd.Series([98, 'hello', 98.9, 'b', 4, 1, 6.7, 'a', 1.4])
>>> s
0       98
1    hello
2     98.9
3        b
4        4
5        1
6      6.7
7        a
8      1.4
dtype: object
>>>
```

As you can see, the different value types are still in mixed order, but they are reversed by the other same type values.

- The integer order was `1, 4, 98` and it's now `98, 4, 1`.
- The float order was `1.4, 6.7, 98.9` and it's now `98.9, 6.7, 1.4`.
- The string order was `'a', 'b', 'hello'` and it's now `'hello', 'b', 'a'`

What I have tried so far is:

```
>>> s.to_frame().groupby([[*map(type, s)]], sort=False).apply(lambda x: x.iloc[::-1]).reset_index(drop=True)
       0
0     98
1      4
2      1
3  hello
4      b
5      a
6   98.9
7    6.7
8    1.4
>>>
```

And yes, they do get reversed in order. But, since I'm using `groupby`, the values are grouped together into separated groups, they're not mixed together.

How would I fix this?

Comment: does the order of different type matters, why in the desired output 98 should be before 'hello'? Why not 98.9, 'hello', 98, ...

Comment: @XYZ The first item in the original series is an integer. So, that means that the first item in the desired output series should be an integer too, the last integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
out = (s.groupby(s.map(type), sort=False)
       .apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.sort_values(ascending=False).tolist(), index=x.index)))
```

`out`

```
0       98
1    hello
2     98.9
3        b
4        4
5        1
6      6.7
7        a
8      1.4
dtype: object
```

Comment: Nice and condensed! I didn't know you could do it inside `apply`! Also didn't think about `pd.Series.map`.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out a solution myself, it's a bit long an inefficient. I would still prefer better solutions though.

This is how I did it:

```py
print(
     s.to_frame().groupby([[*map(type, s)]], sort=False)
     .apply(lambda x: x.reindex(x.index[::-1])
     .rename(index=dict(zip(x.index[::-1], x.index))))
     .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
     .sort_index().squeeze().rename(index=None)
)
```

Output:

```
0       98
1    hello
2     98.9
3        b
4        4
5        1
6      6.7
7        a
8      1.4
dtype: object
```

I use `to_frame` to convert this `Series` into a `DataFrame`, and I use `map` to give me the types of all the values. After that, I use `groupby` to group them and `apply` and `rename` to reverse the order/index of them. The next step is to use `reset_index` to reset the index and sort the values by the index using `sort_index`. Then, I just use `squeeze` to convert this `DataFrame` to a `Series` again, and `rename` to remove the index name.